# Ignore header validation for HTTP requests in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, shoutcast, node-request

I am building a proxy server which is supposed to forward data from an Shoutcast server to the client. Using `request` or even Node's `http` module this fails due to missing HTTP header:

```
{ [Error: Parse Error] bytesParsed: 0, code: 'HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT' }
```

The URL in question is: http://stream6.jungletrain.net:8000

Doing a header request with curl I was able to verify this:

```
$ curl -I http://stream6.jungletrain.net:8000
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Yet the stream is working fine as tested with `curl stream6.jungletrain.net:8000`.

---

Is there a way to disable the header verification in `request` or Node's `http`? This is the code I am testing it on:

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  request('http://stream6.jungletrain.net:8000').pipe(res);
  stream.pipe(res);
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Server started')
});
```

I am aware this can be achieved by rolling an implementation with [`net`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html), there is also [`icecast-stack`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/icecast-stack) but subjectively seen it only implements half of the `Stream` interfaces properly.

Comment: What type of stream is icecast? Also - what's `stream.pipe(res)` doing in your example?

Comment: Recommand you look at https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy for an already node based http proxy implementation. But personally I would not recommand nodejs for a proxy server, and you better off with something like nginx.

Comment: This is NOT an Icecast server. It's Shoutcast, which is NOT HTTP compliant, so no surprise you have problems.

Comment: @TBR Well spotted, how did you find out?

Comment: I'm the Icecast maintainer and know that Icecast doesn't do such crap, but Shoutcast does. ;-)

Comment: @platzhirsch If it's helpful, I have an NPM package that enables streaming from SHOUTcast servers (which are not HTTP-compliant, as TBR said) using the normal Node HTTP client.  They attach to the HTTP client as an Agent and take care of the incompatibility.  It isn't open source... available commercially.  E-mail me at brad@audiopump.co if you're interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`icecast`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/icecast), I was able to get this working both using the `on('data')` event and by piping it to the Express response:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var icecast = require('icecast');

var url = 'http://stream6.jungletrain.net:8000';

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    icecast.get(url, function(icecastRes) {
        console.error(icecastRes.headers);
        icecastRes.on('metadata', function(metadata) {
            var parsed = icecast.parse(metadata);
            console.error(parsed);
        });
        icecastRes.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log(chunk);
        })
    });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server started')
});
```

Or simply:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    icecast.get(url).pipe(res);
});
```

**Also of some note:**

It appears the icecast package has been superseded by https://www.npmjs.com/package/icy

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should have clarified, but I was using the predecessor implementation and it didn't expose a proper `unpipe` or `close` interface.

Comment: So this module does expose those or not? And if it doesn't, I'd suggest the easiest course of action is to try and implement them into icecast and submit a PR.

Comment: Hrm, it also seems that it's been replaced and the old one was never removed from NPM. https://www.npmjs.com/package/icy